# Thread problem in Java: two threads with same priority should have no "order" right?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am practicing how to use Thread in Java. currently I am trying to proof that how two separate threads dealing with shared variables. I created a class:

```
    public class Prac{
        int z = 0;
        public void foo(int i){
            this.z = i;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " updated z to " + z);
            System.out.println("current z is " + this.z);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Prac p = new Prac();

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread1(p));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread2(p));

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }

    }
```

and also two threads:

```
public class MyThread1 implements Runnable{
    Prac p = null;

    public MyThread1 (Prac p){
        this.p=p;
    }

    public void run(){
        p.foo(1);
    }
}

public class MyThread2 implements Runnable{
    Prac p = null;

    public MyThread2 (Prac p){
        this.p=p;
    }

    public void run(){
        p.foo(2);
    }
}
```

I thought the final value of z should be sometimes 1, sometimes 2. However, the final will always be 2. and if I move `t2.start()` before `t1.start()`, the final will always be 1. I thought there should be no specific order of the execution of the two threads with the same priority, right? but why the outcome is not what I expected please?

Thanks

Comment: this is system dependent. Java does not make any assumptions on the way your particular system will manage the threads. If you can, try with Windows, Linux. Then try on a raspberry pi. You most likely will notice behavior variations.

Comment: There is no specified order, but **starting a thread takes time**, so by the time thread #2 gets started, thread #1 is already done.

Comment: @Andreas ... and starting a thread does not means it is running. It is only scheduled to run the run method at some point in the future.

Comment: @spi Yeah, but with computers mostly being multi-core, a second thread will generally start running as soon as it's started. Raspberry Pi being a great example of single-core, though.

Comment: @Andreas right (btw pi4 have 4 cores), but I was just pointing that threading is very dependent of the system, and you can not make assumptions about what will be executed first only from a single execution context. The current load can modify the behavior too (a stressed system likely will delay the execution of new threads, since it is lacking resources to do so)

Comment: @spi My comment was to explain why OP likely sees consistent results on OPs machine. Your comments, while accurate, don't actually address the question *(paraphrased: "Why do **I** see consistent results?")*.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to prove...

The behavior of unsynchronized threads in Java (and in most other programming languages) is *deliberately* left undefined. The reason for that is, there is diversity in the design of different multi-processor systems, and leaving certain behaviors undefined allows the implementors to do things in the most efficient way on any given hardware platform and OS.

But, by giving Java implementors freedom to do things in the most efficient way, they took away your ability to prove anything about threads through testing. A program that behaves in the same way every time you run it on a certain machine on a certain day may behave differently on a different machine, on a different OS, on a different version of the same OS, in a different JVM, on a different day, etc.

If you want to guarantee any particular outcome of a multi-threaded program, the only way you can do it is by using documented synchronization mechanisms and, by inferring how your program will behave based on the guarantees, spelled out in [Chapter 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html) of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/index.html), about what those synchronization mechanisms will do.